# How can I use std::make_tuple at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, std, constexpr

Constexpr function that returns  `std::array<std:tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>, size_t>` does not work at compile time due to the use of std::make_tuple. Is there any way to overcome this?

When I tried to remove constexpr specifiction. It works correctly. However, the goal of our project is to provide such function evaluation at compile time.

I got the following error:

At calling part:

```
error: call to non-constexpr function ‘std::tuple<_Elements>& std::tuple<_Elements>::operator=(std::tuple<_Elements>&&) [with _Elements = {unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int}]’
```

At function part:

```
error: ‘constexpr std::array<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int>, SIZE> GenArrayTuple() [with long unsigned int SIZE = 128]’ called in a constant expression
```

The code is below.

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
constexpr std::array<std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>, SIZE> 
GenArrayTuple() {
  std::array<std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>, SIZE> array;
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    // FIXME constexpr
    arr[2*i] = std::make_tuple(i, i * 2, i * 3 + 1);
  }
  return array;
}

constexpr uint32_t n = 128; 
constexpr auto array_tuple = GenArrayTuple<n>();
```

Comment: `std::make_tuple` is `constexpr` since C++14 [according to cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple). Does your compiler fully support C++14, and are you operating in C++14 or higher mode?

Comment: The error message is not about `make_tuple`, it's about `operator=`, which is in fact not `constexpr` in C++14 or C++17. (But it is in the latest C++20 draft.)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hello! Thanks for your reply. I'm using c++17 with GCC 7.2.0.

Comment: @aschepler I dont know that assignment `operator =` is not supported in current c++1x version. Thank you for your insight. So, you mean that we cannot assign array element at compile time?

Comment: @user9414424: The problem is with `tuple`'s `operator=`. [`array`'s mutating `operator[]` is `constexpr` as of C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at), so `array`s can have their elements assigned at compile time, as long as the element type in question has a `constexpr` `operator=`, it's just that [`tuple` doesn't (until C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually no issue with using [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) in a constant expression in C++14 or later, since C++14 changed it to be `constexpr`.  So it's a valid constant expression, as long as any class constructors used to initialize the tuple's elements evaluate as valid constant expressions (and there are no such constructors when your element types are all scalars like `std::uint32_t`).

But take a better look at the error message.  The function it complains about is (taking out some details) `tuple& tuple::operator=(tuple&&)`.  It turns out the [assignment operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D) of `std::tuple` are not marked `constexpr` in current C++ versions, meaning any assignment of a `tuple` object is not a valid constant expression.  (cppreference.com notes that they will be marked `constexpr` in C++20; this generally reflects changes from a proposal already accepted by the appropriate C++ working group.)

So to work around this, you'll need to initialize the `array` all at once, rather than assigning its elements in a loop.  Probably the easiest way to do this is with the help of [`std::make_integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

template <std::uint32_t ... I>
constexpr std::array<std::tuple<std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t>,
                     sizeof...(I)>
GenArrayTuple_helper(std::integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, I...>) {
    return { std::make_tuple(I, I * 2, I * 3 + 1) ... };
}

template <std::size_t SIZE>
constexpr std::array<std::tuple<std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t>,
                     SIZE> 
GenArrayTuple() {
    return GenArrayTuple_helper(std::make_integer_sequence<std::uint32_t, SIZE>{});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By the way, is `I` a reserved character?? I got an error message `error: expected ‘>’ before ‘(’ token`. Replacing it by `T` could solve.